# RestComm sdk with FreeSwitch sdp error "Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint"

Tags: freeswitch, restcomm

I am trying RestComm android sdk and I connected it with a working FreeSwitch I am able to make call from A RestComm SDK to B RestComm SDK user.

When Receiving party Answers call RestComm shows following error

**RCConnection Error: setSDP Error: Failed to set remote offer sip: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint**

in RestComm signaling is on SIP but Media is handled through WebRTC

I think I need to configure DTLS settings in FreeSwitch. I need help sort this issue out.

Comment: Can you provide a link (gist, pastebin, etc) to full Android logcat for your scenario, so that I can check what is going on?

Best regards

Comment: Inspect the SDP coming from RestComm to Freeswitch. I think SDP is coming without Finger print.

Comment: hi, did you able to fix the issue? i also having the same problem and strucked without a fix

Comment: @SahanMaldeniya This version is very old but now WebRTC has been updated. I had to change alot in the code.. kind of rebuild the structure.